# how to fix the closure bug in my jQuery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

the page always alert "btn2" ,whenever I click btn1 or btn2. it's seem the problem caused the "click" closures.but I don't know how to fixed it.

thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>untitled</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        (function(){
            $.fn.test =  function(){
                F.init.apply(this,arguments)
            };
            var F ={
                that:null,
                init:function(){
                    F.that = this;
                    $(F.that).click(function(e) {
                        F.method();
                    });
                },
                method:function(){
                    var text =$(F.that).html();
                    alert(text);
                }
            }
        })();
        $(function(){
            $("#btn1").test(); //alert btn2---bug
            $("#btn2").test(); //alert btn2
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="btn1">btn1</button>
    <button id="btn2">btn2</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have referred to your object class `F` by that name from within the class.

Your line `F.that = this` is effectively therefore creating what would in other OO languages be considered a "static member" of the class, so both `#btn2` and `#btn1` ended up sharing the same `that` member.

Furthermore, your click handler is trying to call `F.method()` - in effect also a static method call.

You'll need to create a *`new`* object of type `F` each time you wish to wrap it around an element.  Only then will you get a separate `this` for each element.

I suggest using an off-the-shelf jQuery plugin model such as http://jqueryboilerplate.com/ instead of trying to invent your own.  See this extract from that code:

```
$.fn[ pluginName ] = function ( options ) {
    return this.each(function() {
        if ( !$.data( this, "plugin_" + pluginName ) ) {
            $.data( this, "plugin_" + pluginName, new Plugin( this, options ) );
        }
    });
};
```

Note how it uses `new Plugin` to create the plugin instance, and then stores it on the element using `$.data`, but only the first time the plugin is invoked against each element.

Answer (score 0):

1)F is a static Object

2)So F.that is also static

3)so

```
F.that = this
```

line will set 'this' to F.that.
4)first time you call

```
$("#btn1").test();
```

then F.that will be equal to $("#btn1");//this will be equal to $("#btn1")

5)Next time you call

```
$("#btn2").test();
```

then F.that will be equal to $("#btn2");//this will be equal to $("#btn2")

6) So finally to F.that you are setting $("#btn2")

7)hence the $(F.that).html(); is essentially $($("#btn2").html()) which is further same as $("#btn2").html()

8)Hence alert is showing "btn2"